# how to validate header params using Bean Validation and jax-rs

Tags: jax-rs, bean-validation

I have jax-rs resources and each have a same header. what is the best way to validate that the header is present using Bean Validation. I know about @HeaderParam but I don't want to change all my methods in all resources to include the header param.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as implementing `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter`. For example:

```
@Provider
public class ContentTypeValidatorFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) {
        String contentType = getHeader(reqContext, "Content-Type");
        // Content-type validation, but you can valid as many headers as you want.
        if (Objects.isNull(contentType)) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException("Content-Type header is missing");
        }
    }

    private String getHeader(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, String header) {
        return requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst(header);
    }
}
```

Later, to handle this exception gracefully just implement `ExceptionMapper` for this `InvalidRequestException`.

The above filter will be applied globally. But if you want to exclude some endpoints, then make use of `@NameBinding` to annotate your custom annotation and apply it only to specific endpoints.